# ESP8266 crashes when trying to copy a string into a big char

Tags: string

I'm trying to parse with tinyxml2 a modest XML (3.4kb) to retrieve some data.

My ESP8266 crashes every time I try to use the `toCharArray` method.

here's my code

```
// here I'm getting an http request
String payload = https.getString();

// checking the payload, it seems fine in console but I get some garbage characters when àèéùìò are printed
Serial.println(payload);

// Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
int str_len = payload.length() + 1;

// Prepare the character array
char xml[str_len];

// Copy it over
payload.toCharArray(xml, str_len);

// there I'll parse xml with tinyxml2 but the MCU crashes before getting here
```

the length of the string is something around 3900, which I'm not sure can fit this kind of array on this device. If it's the case, what will be a better strategy ?

As you can imagine I'm just starting with the c language :)

EDIT: `https.getString().c_str()` + less variables was the right way to save memory

Comment: variables declared inside functions are created on the stack, the total size of these variables is 4kb - 3900 is getting pretty close - you'll want to use `malloc` (and `free`) to use `heap` memory instead

Comment: another option is, if you know the absolute maximum payload could be, create a global buffer to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function local variable are created on the stack, and in the case of an ESP8266, the total size is limited to 4096 Bytes - so, 3900 for one variable is cutting it close.

I would recommend you either use malloc/free

```
int str_len = payload.length() + 1;

// Prepare the character array
char *xml = (char *) malloc(str_len);

// Copy it over
payload.toCharArray(xml, str_len);

// there I'll parse xml with tinyxml2 but the MCU crashes before getting here
//
// when done, free the memory malloc'd

free(xml);
```

or, if you know an absolute maximum size for the string, e.g. 5000, make `char xml[5001];` in the global scope

Comment: tried declaring a char with a size of 6000 in global and it reboots 

<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa, the size of the string is ~5700

Comment: got a compile error with malloc -> src/main.cpp:74:35: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: yeah, sorry was in a rush - hang on - there, fixed

Comment: `tried declaring a char with a size of 6000 in global and it reboots` - really? that does seem odd

Comment: still no luck (event with malloc, which seems to work fine) but I think the problem could be elsewhere. For the sake of documentation I'll post the gist of the main file -> https://gist.github.com/leRenart/1b72db23371839fd5a7799ece63ad8ed

Comment: so with malloc it crashes with the same "cause"?

Comment: it crashes every time I did a myString.toCharArray(), so I've finally opted to get rid of some variables, and ended with passing the result of the GET directly into the xml parser `          doc.Parse( https.getString().c_str() ); ` I've tested it for many hours without any problem. I think I was using too much memory, but again, I'm not sure (if you wanna take a look into my code I've posted a gist of it). This is frustrating me because for no apparent reason (as the input is the same) this morning is keeping crashing and I can't figure why. To me all of this is learn by (wrong)doing...